# Can Python "os.environ.get" ever return a non-string?

Tags: python, environment-variables

In this code [here](https://github.com/chimpler/pyhocon/blob/master/pyhocon/config_parser.py#L291), they use `os.environ` to get the value of an environment variable, and then immediately check to see if it is an instance of their custom classes.

```
value = os.environ.get(variable)
...
elif isinstance(value, ConfigList) or isinstance(value, ConfigTree):
```

Is it actually possible that the `value` will be an instance of their custom classes? Is this dead code?

Comment: Well, the [documentation states](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) "A mapping object representing the string environment.". That rules out pretty much anything else. Python 3 has `os.environb` if you want bytes instead of `str`s. I have *no clue* how an environment variable would be a `ConfigList` or `ConfigTree`, unless those are defined as `str` (or `NoneType`).

Comment: Is there any evidence that code works? All of that is in an exception handler and it won't really crash if `isinstance` always fails. It is possible that it is just dead code and no one noticed before you did ;)

Comment: @zvone: I actually found it while looking at the lines not covered by their test cases. I couldn't figure out how this code could be executed. The odd part is that this code has been there since the beginning. This code is not a result of a refactor. Oh well, it happens to all of us sometimes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Anything that comes from the *outside* will be just a string, I guess.

On the other hand if you are adding something to the environment from the Python code, then you have just a bit more freedom.

Adding anything but a string still fails:

```
>>> os.environ['a'] = 89
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\os.py", line 420, in __setitem__
    putenv(key, item)
TypeError: must be string, not int
```

However, you could make your own class inherited from str:

```
class C(str):
    pass

os.environ['a'] = C()
```

In Python2 this seems to do the trick:

```
>>> type(os.environ['a'])
<class '__main__.C'>
```

However, in Python 3 it does not. It looks like it just saves a string:

```
>>> type(os.environ['a'])
<class 'str'>
```

---

Still, that does not explain the code from [pyhocon](https://github.com/chimpler/pyhocon/blob/master/pyhocon/config_parser.py#L291). I don't see how that object could be pushed into `os.environ`.

Unless they monkeypatched `os.environ`... In that case, anything would be possible.

Comment: Did you see the `Configtree` and `ConfigList` classes? Subclasses of `OrderDict` and `list`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Yes, I was just writing the addition to my answer.

Comment: > "However, in Python 3 it does not. It looks like it just saves a string". 

Here's the line that does that https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6844dd01dd857ba8e606b5cf4a27cc37b8e2bece/Lib/os.py#L743